# Stop click event on input field to be propagated to map layer

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a simple html text input field within a panel on top of an OpenLayers Map. Everytime I click in the input field, the click event gets propageted to the map. I want the click event not to be propagated to the map when it is within the input field. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour and it's called *Event Bubbling*. I'd recommend you to check this [Bubbling and capturing](https://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing) tutorial for a better understanding.

Anyway, sometimes it's useful to avoid it and you can achieve this by calling:

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

inside your event handler function.